# scrapy webcrawler keyword parameter

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, keyword

I have a scrapy webcrawler that is intended to follow links IF they contain one of my set of keywords.  I get the feeling this is occurring but my output csv file is missing many of the links and I can't figure why.  The spider is below.

```
def find_all_substrings(string, sub):
    starts = [match.start() for match in re.finditer(re.escape(sub), string)]
    return starts

class GraphSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'agavecovidbot'
    custom_settings = {
    'DEPTH_LIMIT': '2',
    }
    allowed_domains = [domain1.com]
    start_urls = ["Domain1.com/specifiedpage1", "Domain1.com/specifiedpage2"]
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), follow=True, callback="parse_item")]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print ("***********************************************************stop")
        yield self.check_buzzwords(response)
        yield self.fetch_links(response)
        yield self.response_downloaded(response)
        
    def check_buzzwords(self, response):
        wordlist = ["key1",
                    "key2"
                    ]
        
        url = response.url
        contenttype = response.headers.get("content-type", "").decode('utf-8').lower()
        data = response.body.decode('utf-8')
        
        for word in wordlist:
            substrings = find_all_substrings(data, word)
            for pos in substrings:
                ok = False
                if not ok:
                    if os.path.exists('1url-to-key.csv'):
                        append_write = 'a'
                    else:
                        append_write = 'w'
                    with open('1url-to-key.csv', append_write) as url_f:
                        url_f.write(word + "&,&" + url + "\n")
        return Item()
    
    def fetch_links(self, response):
        links = LinkExtractor(canonicalize=True, unique=True).extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            if os.path.exists('1url-to-url.csv'):
                append_write = 'a'
            else:
                append_write = 'w'
            
            with open('1url-to-url.csv', append_write) as url_f:
                url_f.write(response.url + "&,&" + link.url + "\n")
        
        return Item()

    def _requests_to_follow(self, response):
        if getattr(response, "encoding", None) != None:
            return CrawlSpider._requests_to_follow(self, response)
        else:
            return []
        
    def response_downloaded(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-1] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)    
        rule = self._rules[response.meta['rule']]
        return self._parse_response(response, rule.callback, rule.cb_kwargs, rule.follow)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix the url-to-key csv file so that it returns all the combinations I'm expecting to see? Thanks!

Comment: I have a few questions, as your spider is a little unusual. What is the purpose of overriding `_requests_to_follow`? Why is `response_download` calling `self._parse_response`?

Comment: I think the override was originally to negate following every link and not only those containing a keyword. But I could be incorrect - some of this was given to me by colleagues.

Comment: I'm also not as well trained in Python as I am in other languages, so there could be inaccuracies in the code that I've missed. Any help or guidance is appreciated!